# Title corresponding plot in pipe

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a list of dataframes, each of which has a grouping variable. I want to plot a barchart for each dataframe and for each group and at the same time, so that the ggtitle of each chart matches the current dataframe name + the value of the current grouping variable.

Minimal data for reproduce:

```
tmp <- list(
    HLA_alpha_A = tibble(group_var = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
                        TR = c("TRAV21", "TRAV13", "TRAV26", "TRAV9"),
                        value = c(132530, 175940, 97014, 144928)),
    HLA_alpha_B = tibble(group_var = c(7, 7, 9, 9),
                        TR = c("TRAV21", "TRAV13", "TRAV26", "TRAV9"),
                        value = c(113892, 181864, 112286, 149134)))
```

And my current code now:

```
tmp %>% 
    map(~ .x  %>% 
       group_by(group_var) %>% 
       group_map(~ .x  %>% 
                ggplot(aes(factor(reorder(TR, -value)), value)) +
                geom_bar(stat="identity") +
                theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))+
                ylab("") +
                xlab("") +
                ggtitle(paste0(names(.x), " allele ", .y))))
```

So far it turns out like this:

[image]

I want the name of the dataframe, not the column, to be substituted, that is, for the first chart, the title should be `HLA_alpha_A allele 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key to solving this is not to use `purrr` style lambda functions, as the inner `group_map()`'s `.y` prevents you from accessing your df's name in the outer `imap()`. Luckily, R 4.1 introduced base lambda functions.

```r
library(tidyverse)

tmp %>% 
    imap(\(d, dname) d %>% 
           group_by(group_var) %>% 
           group_map(\(dsub, grp) dsub %>% 
                    ggplot(aes(factor(reorder(TR, -value)), value)) +
                    geom_bar(stat="identity") +
                    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))+
                    ylab("") +
                    xlab("") +
                    ggtitle(paste0(dname, " allele ", grp))))
#> $HLA_alpha_A
#> $HLA_alpha_A[[1]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> $HLA_alpha_A[[2]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> 
#> $HLA_alpha_B
#> $HLA_alpha_B[[1]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> $HLA_alpha_B[[2]]
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! This is actually what i needed.

Answer (score 2):

Other solution:

```
plots <- mapply(function(xx, yy) {
  print(xx %>% 
    group_by(group_var) %>% 
    group_map(~ .x  %>% 
                ggplot(aes(factor(reorder(TR, -value)), value)) +
                geom_bar(stat="identity") +
                theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))+
                ylab("") +
                xlab("") +
                ggtitle(paste0(yy, " allele ", .y))))
  }, tmp, names(tmp))
```